# Changing subquery to join to update a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, subquery

I was trying to convert the subquery to join in the update statement in order to pursuit of tuning it so as to prevent a deadlock. I was trying in vain to come to the exact update as I've to take the Top 1.

-- create associate table and insert sample data

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Associate](
    [pre_plan_id] [smallint] NULL,
    [pre_type_id] [smallint] NULL,
    [associate_id] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [deleted] [bit] NOT NULL
)  

INSERT INTO Associate 
VALUES 
(NULL,  NULL,   -32768, 0),
(NULL,  NULL,   2,  1),
(NULL,  NULL,   3,  0)
```

-- create visit table and insert sample data

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Visit](
    [type_id] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [plan_id] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [associate_id] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [time_in] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL
) 
INSERT INTO Visit 
VALUES
(390,   31, 3109,   '2009-09-02'),
(304,   32, 3109,   '2010-02-05'),
(388,   31, 3109,   '2010-09-24')
```

--- the update statement

```
UPDATE Associate SET pre_plan_id = 
      (SELECT TOP 1 plan_id 
         FROM Visit  
        WHERE associate_id = Associate.associate_id 
          AND time_in > 90
        GROUP BY plan_id 
        ORDER BY Count(*) DESC)
 WHERE deleted = 0
```

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this one a try:

```
UPDATE a 
SET a.pre_plan_id = z.plan_id
FROM
  associate a
  INNER JOIN
  (
    SELECT associate_id, plan_id 
    FROM
    (
      SELECT associate_id, plan_id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY associate_id ORDER BY ctr DESC) rown
      FROM (SELECT associate_id, plan_id, count(*) as ctr FROM visit WHERE time_in > 90 GROUP BY associate_id, plan_id) x
    ) y
    WHERE rown = 1
  ) z
  ON z.associate_id = a.associate_id
WHERE deleted = 0
```

It's got 3 subqueries only because I can't remember if it's possible to use a grouped count(*) in a window function.. If it is, this may work:

```
UPDATE a 
SET a.pre_plan_id = z.plan_id
FROM
  associate a
  INNER JOIN
  (
    SELECT associate_id, plan_id 
    FROM
    (
      SELECT associate_id, plan_id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY associate_id ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) rown
      FROM visit 
      WHERE time_in > 90 
      GROUP BY associate_id, plan_id
    ) y
    WHERE rown = 1
  ) z
  ON z.associate_id = a.associate_id
WHERE deleted = 0
```

Or even this, shorter form:

```
UPDATE a 
SET a.pre_plan_id = z.plan_id
FROM
  associate a
  INNER JOIN
  (
      SELECT associate_id, plan_id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY associate_id ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) rown
      FROM visit 
      WHERE time_in > 90 
      GROUP BY associate_id, plan_id
  ) z
  ON z.associate_id = a.associate_id AND z.rown = 1
WHERE deleted = 0
```

It seems you want to count up the visits and select the one with the highest number of occurrences of plan_id and then use this to populate pre_plan_id. By grouping and getting the counts, then doing a row_number() over the counts descending it means the highest count will be 1, which we can filter on and pluck out the associated plan_id as the pre_plan_id

Comment: Neither of them update the table. I'll try to take it from here. Thanks though!

Comment: One of the problems with the same data is that the associate ID 3109 in the visits, isn't mentioned in the associate table so this join will produce 0 rows. Also not really sure what `time_in > 90` means if time_in is a date rather than eg a number of minutes someone stayed at a place

Comment: In the original case, it produces 2 rows. But with this one, I've tried it changing the inner join to left join...and it produces 2 rows. I'm not sure if it is a coincidence or it is how it should be.

Comment: I've fixed a small typo in the logic of the row number; I shouldn't have partitioned by plan_id, just by associate. It seems to work ok and update the table, but I did have to edit the Associate table so Associate ID 2 was Associate ID 3109 - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=038aca3e67709abafaeb204ec127aa32